# Drawing the Graph of a complex chemical reaction network

Tags: graphs-and-networks, chemistry

I'm interested in how Mathematica or IGraph/M package can help with the visualization of complex chemical reaction mechanisms applied in fields like combustion, biochemistry, water radiolysis, or ozone-water radical decomposition.
These chemical mechanisms usually involve dozens of chemical species and hundreds of chemical reactions. A convenient way to graphically visualize the mechanism is considering a Graph where the chemical substances are the vertex and the chemical reactions are the edges, directed edges in the chemical sense of reactive and products. Additionally, the edges are weighted by the kinetic rate constants which indicates how fast is the reaction.
With this representation, I would like to identify dead-ends in the reaction chain, radical/substance loops, or the fastest ways from the reactants to products.

I'm using Mathematica for the interpretation and generation of the chemical information of a kinetic mechanism, as all the chemical species (vertex), chemical reactions (edges), and rate constants (edge weights). When I try to build a Graph there are a lot of multiple edges connecting different substances which overloads the graph.

I have two questions for the community:

1. how is in your opinion the best way to build the chemical reaction mechanism graph? Deriving a WeightedAdyacencyMatrix? Now I'm building the graph through string manipulation using EdgeAdd[] but is not an efficient way to do it. With the AdyacencyMatrix, can I define multiple oriented edges?
2. How can I simplify the multiple edges in my Graph without losing the involved information about the chemical reactions in the mechanism?

I'll try to explain with this example. The following reaction mechanism follows from Ershov and Gordeev in Rad. Phys. Chem. 77(2008) 928-935

[image: Table 1. Water radiolisis reaction mechanism]

With Mathematica I transcribed the chemical reaction information in a structure. For instance, the reactions are written as:

```
all={{"<R1>", {"OH", "H2"}, {"H", "H2O"}, 
  "3.74E+7"}, {"<R2>", {"OH", "HO2m"}, {"HO2", "OHm"}, 
  "5E+9"}, {"<R3>", {"OH", "H2O2"}, {"HO2", "H2O"}, 
  "3.8E+7"}, {"<R4>", {"OH", "O2m"}, {"O2", "OHm"}, 
  "9.96E+9"}, {"<R5>", {"OH", "HO2"}, {"O2", "H2O"}, 
  "7.1E+9"}, {"<R6>", {"OH", "OH"}, {"H2O2"}, 
  "5.3E+9"}, {"<R7>", {"OH", "eaq"}, {"OHm"}, 
  "3.0E+10"}, {"<R8>", {"H", "O2"}, {"HO2"}, 
  "2.0E+10"}, {"<R9>", {"H", "O2m"}, {"HO2m"}, 
  "2.0E+10"}, {"<R10>", {"H", "HO2"}, {"H2O2"}, 
  "2.0E+10"}, {"<R11>", {"H", "H2O2"}, {"OH", "H2O"}, 
  "3.44E+7"}, {"<R12>", {"H", "OH"}, {"H2O"}, 
  "7.0E+9"}, {"<R13>", {"H", "H"}, {"H2"}, 
  "7.9E+9"}, {"<R14>", {"eaq", "O2"}, {"O2m"}, 
  "1.94E+10"}, {"<R15>", {"eaq", "O2m"}, {"HO2m", "OHm"}, 
  "1.3E+10"}, {"<R16>", {"eaq", "HO2"}, {"HO2m"}, 
  "2.0E+10"}, {"<R17>", {"eaq", "H"}, {"H2", "OHm"}, 
  "2.5E+10"}, {"<R18>", {"eaq", "H2O2"}, {"OH", "OHm"}, 
  "1.14E+10"}, {"<R19>", {"eaq", "Hp"}, {"H"}, 
  "2.3E+10"}, {"<R20>", {"eaq", "eaq"}, {"H2", "OHm", "OHm"}, 
  "5.6E+9"}, {"<R21>", {"HO2", "O2m"}, {"O2", "HO2m"}, 
  "9.5E+7"}, {"<R22>", {"HO2", "HO2"}, {"O2", "H2O2"}, 
  "8.1E+5"}, {"<R23>", {"HO2", "H2O2"}, {"O2", "OH", "H2O"}, 
  "3.7"}, {"<R24>", {"HO2"}, {"Hp", "O2m"}, 
  "7E+5"}, {"<R25>", {"Hp", "O2m"}, {"HO2"}, 
  "4.5E+10"}, {"<R26>", {"H2O2"}, {"Hp", "HO2m"}, 
  "0.0356"}, {"<R27>", {"Hp", "HO2m"}, {"H2O2"}, 
  "2E+10"}, {"<R28>", {"Hp", "OHm"}, {"H2O"}, 
  "1.4E+11"}, {"<R29>", {"H2O"}, {"Hp", "OHm"}, 
  "2.5E-5"}, {"<R30>", {"H", "OHm"}, {"eaq", "H2O"}, 
  "1.8E+7"}, {"<R31>", {"O2m", "O2m"}, {"O2", "HO2m", "OHm"}, 
  "0.3"}, {"<R32>", {"O2m", "H2O2"}, {"O2", "OHm", "OH"}, 
  "16"}, {"<R33>", {"PHI"}, {"Hp"}, 
  "RadSource()"}, {"<R34>", {"PHI"}, {"OHm"}, 
  "RadSource()"}, {"<R35>", {"PHI"}, {"eaq"}, 
  "RadSource()"}, {"<R36>", {"PHI"}, {"H"}, 
  "RadSource()"}, {"<R37>", {"PHI"}, {"H2"}, 
  "RadSource()"}, {"<R38>", {"PHI"}, {"OH"}, 
  "RadSource()"}, {"<R39>", {"PHI"}, {"H2O2"}, "RadSource()"}}
```

The first element is the reaction tag, the next ones are reactives and products and the last element is the rate constant. Assuming that the chemical substances are the vertex of the graph and the chemical reactions, the edges, I build the object:

```
grf = Flatten[Table[
    Table[
     Table[
      DirectedEdge[all[[k, 2, i]], all[[k, 3, j]], all[[k, 1]]],
      {j, 1, Length[all[[k, 3]]]}],
     {i, 1, Length[all[[k, 2]]]}],
    {k, 1, Length[all]}]
   ];
```

Then, I plot the graph:

```
gm = 
 GraphPlot[grf, 
  VertexLabels -> 
   Placed["Name", Center, Framed[#, Background -> LightYellow] &], 
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific", DirectedEdges -> True, EdgeLabels -> "EdgeTag"]
```

The graph shows the multiple directed edges for the chemical reactions. How this graph could be simplified and extract the quantitative information such as the maximum flux from PHI to the end products?

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqwPM.png): [image: Reaction graph from chemical mechanism of Table 1]

Thank you and best regards,
Javier

Comment: Please add an explicit example, preferably with code.